# MySQL: Use subquery results in another subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to perform the following MySQL query in a Wordpress installation:

1. Get the category IDs where the category name is "Oppskrifter".
2. Get the child categories of all these IDs.
3. Get the children of the resulting child categories (i.e. the children of 2. and the grandchildren of 1.).

I am trying to solve this using subqueries with aliases, but I am not able to make it work nor am I certain that this is the best way of doing it. Here is my current take:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT term_id AS oppskrifter_id
    FROM wp_terms WHERE name = "Oppskrifter"
) AS R1,
(
    SELECT * FROM wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
        ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = "category" AND tt.parent IN (R1)
) AS R2;
```

The first subquery works just fine by itself, but when introducing the second one it does not know what `R1` is yet, thus I get the error `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'R1' in 'having clause'`. If I substitute `R1` by the actual query, `SELECT term_id AS oppskrifter_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name = "Oppskrifter"` I get the error message `ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'term_id'`.

What I was thinking to do here was to get the children (bullet point 2) in the second query and then do the exact same thing for the grandchildren using those results.

What are my options to solve this? What are the proper ways of doing it, both speed-wise and readability-wise?

Comment: `R1` refers multiple columns yet you are trying to search `tt.parent` column in collection of columns.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you want to achieve. Is it rowset of both subqueries or only the last one? Fiddle or example with dummy data would be perfect

Comment: The ideal result is to get a rowset of both subqueries together, since I need to have a mapping from child to grandchild. That is, I need to know which grandchildren belong to which child of the "Oppskrifter" category.

Comment: As far as your current query goes, you can replace R1 with actual query and then use UNION to merge both. Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c97b3/10  I doubt it's what you expect and it's suboptimal anyways. It's just I still struggle to understand expected result

Comment: I changed the data set in your fiddle and put it here (the query went away for some reason): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/100af I cannot get the SQL to run though, it just says something went wrong. The query I used is the exact same as you had, except I changed "Oppskrifter" to "Recipes". I hope the data set there is clearer as to what I want to achieve: I need to get "Dinner", "Lunch", "Dessert" together with their children categories ("Meat", "Chicken", "Vegetarian", etc.), but "Christmas"  is to be left out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join` on all 3 tables.

*Note: Replace `wp_grand_child` with actual table name and `wg.term_id` with actual field name*

```
SELECT wt.term_id AS oppskrifter_id, wtt.term_id AS child_id, wg.term_id AS grand_child_id
FROM wp_terms AS wt
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS wtt ON wtt.term_id = wt.term_id
JOIN wp_grand_child AS wg ON wg.term_id = wtt.term_id
WHERE wt.name = "Oppskrifter"
AND wtt.taxonomy = "category"
```